# ZfcUser Redirect Roles to different Pages after Login

Tags: zend-framework2, zfcuser, bjyauthorize

I'm using the ZfcUser and BjyAuthorize in my Project. If a user logged in, he will be redirected to my default route.

But i want to change it, so if a User with role A will redirected to Page A and user with role B will redirected to page B.

Any idea, how to realize this?

Comment: You would have to overwrite the `UserController#authenticateAction()`, this requires you to also overwrite the invokable `zfcuser` to your controller. The catch is that you'll have to provide the view-templates from your Module, too ;) It's alittle tricky and quite frankly ZfcUser could need a rewrite :D

Comment: Thank you, for your comment. I have already overwritten the `UserController`, to add new Actions. But i try to solve my problem with your proposal for solution.

Comment: You can try to redirect on signup to a page (to process some actions) and then redirect to their correct user's page (according their role)

Comment: I already implemented Sam solution. The important thing is the entry `'zfcuser' => 'App\Controller\LoginController',` as a invokable in the `module.config.php`

Answer (score 1):

I have actually done this and created the merge request in GitHub. It's actually a very small change that needs to be done in zfc-user/src/ZfcUser/Controlelr/UserController.php. Within authenticateAction() you need to replace this:

```
return $this->redirect()->toRoute($this->getOptions()->getLoginRedirectRoute());
```

For this:

```
$route = $this->getOptions()->getLoginRedirectRoute();

if(is_callable($route)) {
    $route = $route($this->zfcUserAuthentication()->getIdentity());
}

return $this->redirect()->toRoute($route);
```

And in your config/autoload/module.zfcuser.global.php file you'll be able to use a callback for the login_redirect_route:

```
'login_redirect_route' => function(\ZfcUser\Entity\UserInterface $user) {
    if($user->getUsername()=='Admin') {
        return 'admin';
    }

    return 'user';
}
```

Comment: Hi Marc, like you see in the comments above, i already solved the problem by overwriting the `UserController::authenticateAction()`. But your solution looks like a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

As I have to check several things depending on the role I've create a simple module than once the users is logged (default route after loggin)  and depending on the role (avaliable through bjyautorize) redirects the application to the correc url.

Maybe it's not an elegant way but you don't have to modify zfcUser code.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup redirect after login in config file.

```
'login_redirect_route' => '/your-url',
```

`your-url` accessible from all type of user and then create switch case to match your role and redirect page to role specific page.

```
$roles = $this->serviceLocator->get('BjyAuthorize\Provider\Identity\ProviderInterface')->getIdentityRoles();


switch ($roles){

     case "admin": 
            $this->redirect()->toRoute('user_admin'); 
     case "user":              
           $this->redirect()->toUri('user.html');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have an 'admin' role in bjyauthorize that you want to redirect to another route.

In your loginAction replace the code:

```
    if ($this->zfcUserAuthentication()->getAuthService()->hasIdentity()) {
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute($this->getOptions()->getLoginRedirectRoute());
    }
```

with this code:

```
    if ($this->zfcUserAuthentication()->getAuthService()->hasIdentity()) {
        $roles = $this->serviceLocator->get('BjyAuthorize\Provider\Identity\ProviderInterface')->getIdentityRoles();
        if (in_array('admin',$roles))
        {
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('admin_route');
        } else {
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('user_route');
        }
    }
```